# A faster way to open an .CR2 file in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a function that works great when opening JPG and PNG files, but  locks my computer up when opening a CR2 file. The CRS files are coming from my Canon EOS Rebel T6 Camera and they are big, see: [image]

but I feel like it should not lock my computer up and it should not move this slow.

here is my code :

```
  public async Task OpenFile()
    {
        OriginalImage = null;
        await SetProcessBarInformation(0, "Openning Image file");
        OpenFileDialog _openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();   
       if (_openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                await SetProcessBarInformation(20, "Openning Image file");
                FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_openFileDialog.FileName);
                BitmapImage tempOriginalImage = await GetPicture(_openFileDialog.FileName);
                Height = (int)tempOriginalImage.Height;
                Width = (int)tempOriginalImage.Width;

                
                await SetProcessBarInformation(80, "Openning Image file");
             
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                  OriginalImage = tempOriginalImage;

                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }



    protected  async Task<BitmapImage> GetPicture(string tempImage)
    {
        BitmapImage timage = null;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
        timage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(tempImage));
        timage.Freeze();
        });

        return timage;
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, your GetPicture method does not need to be async. You could declare it as `protected Task<BitmapImage> GetPicture(string tempImage) { return Task.Run(() => { var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(tempImage)); bitmap.Freeze(); return bitmap; }); }`

Comment: It is not the matter of image file format but you failed to offload the initialization of `BitmapImage` from UI thread. You used the constructor with `Uri` and so the initialization is actually delayed and done when the `BitmapImage` is consumed by `Image` on UI thread. You can check it by inserting some intervals and watching when CPU usage hikes.

Comment: @ enoacht, thank , so How do you offload the initialization of the BitmapImage from the UI thread?